# How to use PHP to grade multiple choice questions on a form

Tags: php

The people on this board are the some of the smartest people that I know, so I am turning here for some support...

I am not extremely web savvy, but I am a Social Studies teacher and I am trying to build a website that has online tests for my students to complete at home.

I am not a programmer, so I purchased a starter web address with a web site designing kit on it, so that I could create the test as a form.

I want the students to watch videos, then answer questions about the videos that I put into a form.

My question is---  Since most of the questions are T/F or Multiple Choice, How can I set things up so that when the student's tests are submitted to me, any questions that can be graded by a computer are already graded, so that I only have to grade the fill-in and essay questions???

Here is an example of one of the test forms that I have on the site that has 16 questions--

```
<div id="content">

  <div id='wsite-content' class='wsite-not-footer'>
<div class='wsite-not-footer'>
<div  class="paragraph editable-text"><font size="2"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><br /><font style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" color="#33ccff">There are 3 videos that go with&nbsp;Step 1.&nbsp; </font></span></font><font style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" color="#33ccff"><br /><span></span><br /><span style="font-weight: bold;">After you watch each video there will be questions that you will need to answer about that video.&nbsp; Once you have completed the questions for all 3 videos, then hit 'SUBMIT' and your answers will be sent out to be graded.</span></font><br /><br /></div>

<div >
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.dragndropbuilder.com/editor/apps/formSubmit.php" method="POST" id="form-775529455932787620">
<div id="775529455932787620-form-parent" class="wsite-form-container" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <ul class="formlist" id="775529455932787620-form-list">
    <h2  style=" text-align: center; "><FONT size=2>Use the 3 videos to answer questions 1-16 and then submit them for review.</FONT></h2>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-545537524713528365">Enter your User ID# <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-545537524713528365" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u545537524713528365" style="width:100px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-545537524713528365" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;">The User ID# that was assigned to you
(YA#)</div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-712144062427340201">Email <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-712144062427340201" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u712144062427340201" style="width:370px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-712144062427340201" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<h2  style=" text-align: center; "><br /><span></span>Video #1</h2>

<div  style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; "><div style="text-align: center;"><object width="300" height="247"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rT3QOqttWj4"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><param name="allownetworking" value="internal"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rT3QOqttWj4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allownetworking="internal" wmode="transparent" width="300" height="247"></embed></object></div></div>

<h2  style=" text-align: center; "><br /><span></span>Video #1 Questions</h2>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-186019324657526747">1)  You learned about 2 types of creeds- what were they?  <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='checkbox' name='_u186019324657526747[A)  Internal Creed]' value='1' /><label>A)  Internal Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='checkbox' name='_u186019324657526747[B)  Behavioral Creed]' value='1' /><label>B)  Behavioral Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='checkbox' name='_u186019324657526747[C)  Emotional Creed]' value='1' /><label>C)  Emotional Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='checkbox' name='_u186019324657526747[D)  Intellectual Creed]' value='1' /><label>D)  Intellectual Creed</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-1)  You learned about 2 types of creeds- what were they? " class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-483240168633160132">2)  Which creed is the most ideal for making good decisions? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u483240168633160132' value='A)  Internal Creed' /><label>A)  Internal Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u483240168633160132' value='B)  Behavioral Creed' /><label>B)  Behavioral Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u483240168633160132' value='C)  Intellectual Creed' /><label>C)  Intellectual Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u483240168633160132' value='D)  All of the above' /><label>D)  All of the above</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u483240168633160132' value='E)  None of the above' /><label>E)  None of the above</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-2)  Which creed is the most ideal for making good decisions?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-746217096361999826">3)  Which creed is the one that we usually use when we make decisions? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u746217096361999826' value='A)  Emotional Creed' /><label>A)  Emotional Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u746217096361999826' value='B)  Behavioral Creed' /><label>B)  Behavioral Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u746217096361999826' value='C)  Intellectual Creed' /><label>C)  Intellectual Creed</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u746217096361999826' value='D)  All of the above' /><label>D)  All of the above</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u746217096361999826' value='E)  Both A &amp; B' /><label>E)  Both A &amp; B</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-3)  Which creed is the one that we usually use when we make decisions?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-434256132673880428">4)  Why is self-assessment & awareness important on a daily basis? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-434256132673880428" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u434256132673880428" style="width:370px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-434256132673880428" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-444728886557485101">5)  What does it mean when Dr. Benzio says that we need to do maintenance work to prevent crisis work? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-444728886557485101" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u444728886557485101" style="width:370px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-444728886557485101" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-547180780270073494">6)  What stands out as the most important thing that you learned by watching this video?  <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-547180780270073494" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u547180780270073494" style="width:370px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-547180780270073494" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<h2  style=" text-align: center; "><br /><span></span>Video #2</h2>

<div  style=" margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; "><div style="text-align: center;"><object width="300" height="247"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/WYE123qP6dc"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><param name="allownetworking" value="internal"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/WYE123qP6dc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allownetworking="internal" wmode="transparent" width="300" height="247"></embed></object></div></div>

<h2  style=" text-align: center; "><br /><span></span>Video #2 Questions</h2>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-329313228349741149">7)  People have a fear of the unknown because they are creatures of habit. <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u329313228349741149' value='A)  True' /><label>A)  True</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u329313228349741149' value='B)  False' /><label>B)  False</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-7)  People have a fear of the unknown because they are creatures of habit." class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-775199879195536251">8)  Do you want change to happen in your life?  Why or why not? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-775199879195536251" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u775199879195536251" style="width:370px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-775199879195536251" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-251551848140163874">9)  What is the smallest piece that we can break down life into? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u251551848140163874' value='A)  Molecules' /><label>A)  Molecules</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u251551848140163874' value='B)  Days' /><label>B)  Days</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u251551848140163874' value='C)  Minutes' /><label>C)  Minutes</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u251551848140163874' value='D)  Decisions' /><label>D)  Decisions</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-9)  What is the smallest piece that we can break down life into?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-903706497668752803">10)  What does Dr. Benzio refer to as the "key to life"? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
    <input id="input-903706497668752803" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u903706497668752803" style="width:370px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="instructions-903706497668752803" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-350633213472754726">11)  What is this course really about? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u350633213472754726' value='A)  How to get out of trouble' /><label>A)  How to get out of trouble</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u350633213472754726' value='B)  How to score higher on tests' /><label>B)  How to score higher on tests</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u350633213472754726' value='C)  Making better decisions' /><label>C)  Making better decisions</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u350633213472754726' value='D)  Figuring out ways that people will like you better' /><label>D)  Figuring out ways that people will like you better</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-11)  What is this course really about?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<h2  style=" text-align: center; "><br /><span></span>Video #3</h2>

<div  style=" margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; "><div style="text-align: center;"><object width="300" height="247"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/TVRr5HHRUhk"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><param name="allownetworking" value="internal"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TVRr5HHRUhk" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allownetworking="internal" wmode="transparent" width="300" height="247"></embed></object></div></div>

<h2  style=" text-align: center; "><br /><span></span>Video #3 Questions</h2>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-415479768763719608">12)  What do these SPECT scans of the brain show us?  <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u415479768763719608' value='A)  How smart a person is' /><label>A)  How smart a person is</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u415479768763719608' value='B)  How smart a person COULD BE' /><label>B)  How smart a person COULD BE</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u415479768763719608' value='C)  Brain activity- What&#039;s actually going on in the brain' /><label>C)  Brain activity- What&#039;s actually going on in the brain</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u415479768763719608' value='D)  How long until the next meal is necessary' /><label>D)  How long until the next meal is necessary</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-12)  What do these SPECT scans of the brain show us? " class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-517463426874736495">13)  Brain chemistry can change dramatically in just 8 days- True or False?   <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u517463426874736495' value='A)  True' /><label>A)  True</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u517463426874736495' value='B)  False' /><label>B)  False</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-13)  Brain chemistry can change dramatically in just 8 days- True or False?  " class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-886916715838687323">14)  Once brain cells are damaged, they can never be repaired- True or False? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u886916715838687323' value='A)  True' /><label>A)  True</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u886916715838687323' value='B)  False' /><label>B)  False</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-14)  Once brain cells are damaged, they can never be repaired- True or False?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-192117433637760155">15)  What happened to the damaged brains after treatment according to SPECT scans? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u192117433637760155' value='A)  The brain chemistry stayed the same' /><label>A)  The brain chemistry stayed the same</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u192117433637760155' value='B)  The brain chemistry improved' /><label>B)  The brain chemistry improved</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u192117433637760155' value='C)  The brain chemistry got worse' /><label>C)  The brain chemistry got worse</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-15)  What happened to the damaged brains after treatment according to SPECT scans?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>

<div ><div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-846595324763565200">16)  Our brains are in a constant stage of change, both positive and negative- True or False? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <div class="wsite-form-radio-container">
    <span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u846595324763565200' value='A)  True' /><label>A)  True</label></span>
<span class='form-radio-container'><input type='radio' name='_u846595324763565200' value='B)  False' /><label>B)  False</label></span>

  </div>
  <div id="instructions-16)  Our brains are in a constant stage of change, both positive and negative- True or False?" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;"></div>
</div></div>


  </ul>
</div>
<div style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
  <input type="text" name="wsite_subject" />
</div>
<div style="text-align:left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_version" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="wsite_approved" id="wsite-approved" value="approved" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ucfid" value="775529455932787620" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>


</div>
```

Comment: Wow,  please don't post that much code, it is far too much for anyone to look at.

Answer (score 2):

That page is a mess. Your website design kit really seems to love random numbers.

Anyway, what matters is the `name` attribute of each `<input>` element. For example, the name of the User ID input box is `_u545537524713528365`. Similarly, all five radio buttons for the second question have the name `_u483240168633160132`, and only differ in `value`, since only one of them will be selected.

Since you tagged your question "php", I'm assuming that you're planning to write this automated grading program in PHP. The `<form>` tag says `method="POST"`, so the contents of each student's submission will be accessible as `$_POST['name']` inside the PHP program that is referenced by the `action` attribute of the form.

For example, the variable `$_POST['_u545537524713528365']` will contain the User ID, and the variable  `$_POST['_u483240168633160132']` will contain whatever was in the `value` attribute of the radio button that the student selected. Once you have all that data in a PHP program, it's just a matter of comparing it with the right answer one by one. (All these random numbers are getting really inconvenient, which is why you should give human-readable names to your form elements.)

What you do after that is up to you. Maybe your program will count the number of correct answers and e-mail it to you, save it in a database, etc. But all of that is completely beyond what a single answer here can provide. StackOverflow is a great resource for people who want to find out answers to specific questions, but you'll probably be disappointed if you try to learn a whole new programming language using this site. There are better resources for doing that.

Meanwhile, here are some other questions that you could be asking yourself:

1. This thing is going to take dozens, if not hundreds, of hours. Just imagine how much time it would take to program each and every question in this way. (Not just the design, but also the code to grade it.) Maybe you should just download a program that does the same thing?
2. Your first program is 100% likely to contain security flaws. Tech-savvy students may abuse it to their advantage, and you'll never know. There may even be legal or other regulatory restrictions on using a freshly written, insecure web app to grade students' works.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Google Forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/) and just work with spreadsheets, you're going to have a lot easier time working with that than learning how to do web development:

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you surely could. It'd be a fair bit of work from scratch, especially if you're not familiar with PHP and/or MySQL.

Your best bet would be to find a web application that could handle this for you...